# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'page'

Tags: typescript, nativescript

Here is my page.ts

**page.ts**

```
var viewModel : launchViewModelModule.LaunchViewModel;
viewModel = new launchViewModelModule.LaunchViewModel();

export function navigatingTo(args: observableModule.EventData) {
    var page = <pageModule.Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
    }
function showLoginPageForm(slow){
                var initialContainer = page.getViewById("initial-container");
                var mainContainer = page.getViewById("container");
                var containerLogo = page.getViewById("container-logo");
    }
```

inside the showLoginPageForm another local function to the page.ts file shows the

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'page'
```

I don't know what I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after taking a look at a project already done with nativescript-typescript

```
var viewModel : launchViewModelModule.LaunchViewModel;
viewModel = new launchViewModelModule.LaunchViewModel();

let initialContainer: StackLayout;
let mainContainer: StackLayout;
let containerLogo: AbsoluteLayout;


export function navigatingTo(args: observableModule.EventData) {
    var page = <pageModule.Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;

    initialContainer = <StackLayout>page.getViewById("initial-container");
    mainContainer = <StackLayout>page.getViewById("container");
    containerLogo = <AbsoluteLayout>page.getViewById("container-logo");
    runAnimation();    
}
```

Then from here the calling functions e.g `showLoginPageForm()` can have access `initialContainer.animate()` to all its properties and methods  belonging to the object you want to use. Thanks @Kirby

Answer (score 1):

If you need global variables inside local functions you should consider using function parameters or a class based object.

A class based solution (as far as i can call it a solution)

```
class Navigator {

    protected page: pageModule.Page;
    protected viewModel: launchViewModelModule.LaunchViewModel;

    constructor(viewModel: launchViewModelModule.LaunchViewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public navigateTo(args: observableModule.EventData): void {

        this.page = args.object as pageModule.Page;
        this.page.bindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    public showLoginPageForm(slow) {

        const initialContainer = this.page.getViewById("initial-container");
        const mainContainer = this.page.getViewById("container");
        const containerLogo = this.page.getViewById("container-logo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to export the Navigator class because, my xml file is not reading the navigationTo method

Comment: I am not sure what you are willing to do with this xml file and the navigator class. You could open a new question and tell us what you want to do incl. xml file. Otherwise give me a brief overview of your problem.

What i think to your question: You should `export` the navigator class to use it in another file. than instantiate this object using the `new` keyword and exec the function `navigateTo(...)`. I would suggest using a [Singleton design pattern](http://amanvirk.me/singleton-classes-in-es6/)

Answer (score 0):

Variable `page` is defined as a local variable within function `navigatingTo` and is not visible to function `showLoginPageForm`.

Maybe you want to declare `page` outside the functions so that it would be visible to both of them.

Comment: Thanks @Kirby but then if I should declare it outside I would not have access to the getViewById() method that Typed ViewBase. This works normally with nativescript vanilla but failed working with nativescript typescript